# Spring log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.classname). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

When I am running my springboot application, I am getting this error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.system.Config).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I added log4j2.xml in the src/main/resources and I added the below configurations also.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Still my logs are not getting read.

Comment: It will work. Follow here https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-log4j-2-example/

Comment: i used the same, but it got worked when i added apache log4j dependencies